# Friend function in template (why does this fail in Visual Studio but not GCC and Clang)

Tags: c++

Given the following (stripped down and contrived to highlight the problem):

```
#include <utility>

namespace Generic
{
    class Whatever
    {
    public:
        // ISSUE1 (member "swap()" has same name as non-member template)
        void swap()
        {
        }
    };

    // Forward declaration of class template "Test"
    template <class>
    class Test;

    // Prototype of function template "swap()" for class template "Test"
    template<class T>
    void swap(Test<T> &, Test<T> &);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Class template "Test"
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template <class T>
    class Test : public T
    {
    public:
        // Default constructor
        Test() = default;

        // Move constructor
        Test(Test &&test)
            : BaseClass(std::move(test))
        {
        }

        // Assignment operator
        Test& operator=(Test test)
        {
            // Note that the "Generic:" prefix here has no impact on the results
            Generic::swap(*this, test);

            return (*this);
        }

    private:
        using BaseClass = T;

        // ISSUE2 (qualified call - prefixing with "Generic:")
        friend void Generic::swap<T>(Test &, Test &);
    };

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Canonical swap function for class "Test" just above
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    template<class T>
    void swap(Test<T> &, Test<T> &)
    {
    }

} // namespace Generic

int main()
{
    using namespace Generic;
    Test<Whatever> test1;
    Test<Whatever> test2;
    test2 = std::move(test1);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone see any reason why it shouldn't compile. Note in particular ISSUE1 and ISSUE2 in the comments. These affect the results. There are 4 combinations of ISSUE1 and ISSUE2 to try and get things working (see table below), though I am aware of another way to correct things but these 4 combinations are what I want to focus on. Note that all 4 combinations compile cleanly in GCC and Clang, but only item 4 compiles cleanly in Visual Studio 2017 (latest version). The other combinations (1 to 3) fail with the errors seen in the RESULT column below (the compiler cites a problem with the ISSUE2 line in all 3 cases):

```
   ISSUE1                               ISSUE2                          RESULT
   ------                               ------                          ------
1) Leave unchanged                      Leave unchanged                 'Generic::Test': use of class template requires template argument list
                                                                        'Generic::swap': not a function

2) Leave unchanged                      Remove "Generic:" qualifier     syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
                                                                        'swap': illegal use of type 'void'
                                                                        'Generic::swap': 'friend' not permitted on data declarations
                                                                        'Generic::swap': redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
                                                                        unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

3) Comment out member "swap()"          Leave unchanged                 'Generic::Test': use of class template requires template argument list
                                                                        'Generic::swap': not a function

4) Comment out member "swap()"          Remove "Generic:" qualifier     Works!!!
```

Is Visual Studio just buggy or do GCC and Clang have it wrong (the former appears to be the case based on my understanding of the qualified/unqualified name lookup rules, ADL, etc.). Thanks.

Comment: There's no ADL going on here as far as I can see, as all your calls are fully-qualified. I strongly suspect this is related to MSVC's lack of two-phase lookup, but I'll leave it to an expert to diagnose that for definite.

Comment: After changing the friend declaration to `friend void Generic::swap<T>(Test<T> &, Test<T> &);` I was able to compile the above code in VS2017 Version 15.2 (26430.16) without any problem

Comment: @Tristan: Ok, thanks. I am aware of the ADL situation which only kicks in when unqualified of course. The results vary though depending on what changes are made (where ADL may factor in). I'll look into the two-phase lookup situation. Thanks.

Comment: @Artemy Thanks but that doesn't work for me either unless I change the entire line to template<class T> friend void swap(Test<T> &, Test<T> &); (making it a full template declaration). I was already aware of that but I don't want to provide friendship to all specializations, only the current one. It should work as-is AFAIK.

Comment: Please post the full text of the error message and indicate offending lines in the source.

Comment: @n.m.: I did post the full error messages. See the RESULT column in the table. All messages apply to the ISSUE2 line as mentioned in my original post (there are multiple error messages produced by the compiler, but all of them cite the ISSUE2 line).

Comment: @Tristan: Ok, it does appear to be an issue with two-phase lookup (and MSFT's lack of support of it until recently). When I include the "/permissive-" switch which MSFT documents in various sources (dealing with two-phase lookup), the problem disappears. More research to do but I'm probably on the right track now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Heh, found the blog:
[Two-phase name lookup support comes to MSVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/).

Some relevant excerpts:

> The original design of templates for C++ meant to do exactly what the term “template” implied: a template would stamp out families of classes and functions. It allowed and encouraged, but did not require, early checking of non-dependent names. Consequently, identifiers didn’t need to be looked up during parsing of the template definition. Instead, compilers were allowed to delay name lookup until the template was instantiated. Similarly, the syntax of a template didn’t need to be validated until instantiation. Essentially, the meaning of a name used in a template was not determined until the template was instantiated.
>
> In accordance with these original rules, previous versions of MSVC did very limited template parsing.  In particular, function template bodies were not parsed at all until instantiation. The compiler recorded the body of a template as a stream of tokens that was replayed when it was needed during instantiation of a template where it might be a candidate.

The article then goes on to post some code very similar to [n.m.’s minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475789/2706707).

> It’s important to note that overloads declared after the point of the template’s definition but before the point of the template’s instantiation are only considered if they are found through argument-dependent lookup. MSVC previously didn’t do argument-dependent lookup separately from ordinary, unqualified lookup so this change in behavior may be surprising.

Finally, a note about making MSVC use the updated two-phase template parsing:

> You’ll need to use the [/permissive- conformance switch](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/) to enable two-phase lookup in the MSVC compiler included with Visual Studio 2017 “15.3”. Two-phase name lookup drastically changes the meaning of some code so the feature is not enabled by default in the current version of MSVC.

Comment: Yes, that's the same article I found earlier (after researching Tristan Brindle's comment about two-phase lookup). The /permissive switch fixes the problem, at least in the latest version of VS2017. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

Changing...

```
friend void Generic::swap<T>(Test &, Test &);
```

to

```
friend void Generic::swap<T>(Test<T> &, Test<T> &);
```

... allows this to compile. However as mentioned by n.m, Test is an injected class name, and one should be able to omit T inside it's class definition

Comment: Thanks, but strangely it doesn't work either. I'll have to look into why it's working for you and "Artemy" (see my previous response to his comment). Will check out the version of VS he cited but again, it should work as-is AFAIK.

Comment: Yeah, go figure. My version isn't too far behind the online version (very close) so it's strange it doesn't work in my own environment (maybe some switch at play they have turned on automatically). Anyway, it turns out to be a two-phase lookup problem as suspected by Tristan Brindle (see his comment and my last response to him).

Comment: @mikestz, why do you not want to rely on ADL, as Test is already in the correct namespace.

Comment: The real-world situation is more complicated but basically, the (unqualified) name lookup rules normally means that a name in a base class will be found before one at namespace scope. "friend" functions also complicate things depending on whether they're defined in or out of class, and adding templates to the mix only makes things worse. The upshot is my earlier version of VS (I'm not actually using VS2017 yet) isn't fully compliant with all the rules including ADL so for now my hands are tied (am setting up "#if _MSC_VER" in my code to do the right thing depending on the version).

Comment: `Test` is an injected-class-name within `Test` declaration and can be used with or without `<T>` per 17.7.1 (temp.local) p1.

Comment: @n.m., yes of course you're right, it is an injected class name and therfore T can be omitted. I knew that but somehow I missed that we were in Test's definition, because of swap and test's forward declaration prior.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the real minimal example.

```
   template <class> struct Test;
   template <class T> void moo(Test<T>&){};

   template <class T>
   struct Test
   {
       friend void ::moo<T>(Test &);
   };

   Test<int> x;
```

Lookup rules have nothing to do to the problem, which is clearly a compiler bug. It can be inhibited by seemingly unrelated changes, like removing `::` from the `friend` declaration.

The reason of the failure is revealed by the error message:

> 'Test': use of class template requires template argument list

Since `Test` is an *injected-class-name*, it *can* be used without a template argument list, but MSVC apparently forgets about this rule under some unknown set of circumstances. This seems to only happen within a `friend` declaration (not any other declaration or definition) when the declared name is qualified with the namespace name. Determining the exact conditions that trigger the bug is not very interesting or productive though.

The second error message

> 'moo': not a function

is an induced one: since the compiler finds an "error" in the friend declaration of `moo`, the declaration is labelled as erroneous. The same "not a function" error is emitted if you replace `Test` in the parameter list with an undeclared identifier.

Using `Test<T>` is a workaround.

Presence of a base class member with the same name triggers what seems to be a different issue in MSVC which is related to the (lack of) two-phase lookup. Here's the minimal example:

```
template <class> void moo() {}

struct Base
{
    void moo() {}
};

template <class T>
struct Test : T
{
    friend void moo<T>();
};

Test<Base> tb;
```

In this example, the compiler fails to bind  `moo` to the global template at the first phase of name resolution, and gets confused when the template is instantiated and `moo` gets incorrectly resolved to the member of the base class. This works differently from the previous issue, where `moo` is bound to the global template whether or not two phase lookup is implemented. Unlike the first example, here the bug is only triggered if `moo` in the friend declaration is unqualified.

Comment: It is an issue with the way VS has implemented template resolution. Update your compiler to VS 2017.

Comment: @Dúthomhas No, the same bug exists in 2017, it is just triggered under different conditions. Example updated to trigger the bug in MSVC 19.12.25715.0.

Comment: I appreciate your example but it changes the landscape of the original question so it's not "minimal" IMHO. The compiler has to look for the "swap" function which is affected by many issues, in particular where unqualified (UQ) names are involved (bringing ADL into play). The compiler generally searches for UQ names from inner to outer scopes to find the first matching name, so base class versions of the same name will impact the situation. There are many esoteric rules involved (and templates don't help) so it's not "clearly a compiler bug". It might cause fits for even a language lawyer.

Comment: ... not "clearly a compiler bug" until one knows it is of course (which I wasn't previously sure of - easy now in hindsight :)

Comment: @mikestz these additional complicated rules have nothing to do with the bug. The bug itself is a simple failure to recognise that the template name `Test` may be used without accompanying template arguments because it's an injected class name. The exact set of conditions needed to trigger the bug may be very complicated and involve ADL, scopes, namespaces, or nasal demons, but the failure itself has nothing to do with any of those.

Comment: @n.m. Well, I came here for help and don't want to start any debates about the exact cause since only MSFT would know of course (respectfully). I only wanted to confirm there is a bug according to the standard. In the context of my original issue though, the presence of "swap()" in the base class is clearly affecting things. I have to deal with that in my real world situation so the exclusion of it in your own example renders the description of "real minimal example" unsuitable and misleading (which isn't meant to be confrontational but factually correct IMHO).

Comment: @mikestz Presence of a base class member triggers the two-phase name lookup bug in MSVC (the bug is that it isn't implemented of course). Seems to be a different issue from the first one. Updated the answer with this info.